# WordPress login is not working in wamp server

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I have uploaded a WordPress theme in localhost all back up and database file. I can visit my site via localhost but I cant login by previous password. After that I have changed md5 hash from database `wp_user` file `user_pass`. But it is still not working. What can I do?

Comment: I believe the hash is salted

Comment: Reset password via the link?

Answer (score 0):

The username and password should remain the same in the database dump.

Please setup the original database backup to undo the changes to the user table on your local.

Make sure the site root and admin panel URL's in the wp_options table reference the local host environment and not the previous environment.

Make sure the credentials actually work where the site was previously hosted...